# Run jmx file using java

Tags: jmeter, jmx

I created a jmx file using java code. But when i tried to execute the jmx file using java, it  throws the exception. Pls help me.. I have added all the jars. 
(Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/home/ksahu/MyScreenshots/k.jmx', conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: null : null)

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
    import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler;
    import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
    import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
    import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;

    public class RunJMXfile {

        public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
            // JMeter Engine
            StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();


            // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
            JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/home/ksahu/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/jmeter.properties");
            JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/home/ksahu/apache-jmeter-2.13");
            JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
            JMeterUtils.initLocale();

            // Initialize JMeter SaveService
            SaveService.loadProperties();



            // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/home/ksahu/MyScreenshots/k.jmx");
            HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
            in.close();

            // Run JMeter Test
            jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
            jmeter.run();
        }
    }
```

This is the code that i have used to generate the jmx file

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.SetupThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;


public class jmeterTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        // Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jm = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/home/ksahu/apache-jmeter-2.13");

        // jmeter.properties
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/home/ksahu/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/jmeter.properties");

        HashTree hashTree = new HashTree();     

        // HTTP Sampler
        HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSampler.setDomain("www.google.com");
        httpSampler.setPort(80);
        httpSampler.setPath("/");
        httpSampler.setMethod("GET");

        // Loop Controller
        TestElement loopCtrl = new LoopController();
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setLoops(1);
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).addTestElement(httpSampler);
        ((LoopController)loopCtrl).setFirst(true);

        // Thread Group
        SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController((LoopController)loopCtrl);

        // Test plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("MY TEST PLAN");

        hashTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
        hashTree.add("loopCtrl", loopCtrl);
        hashTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
        hashTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);       
        jm.configure(hashTree);



        jm.run();
        System.out.println(hashTree);
        SaveService.saveTree(hashTree,new FileOutputStream("/home/ksahu/MyScreenshots/k.jmx"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the stack trace? Also please attach it.

Comment: yes i tried reading stack trace.

Comment: Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/home/ksahu/MyScreenshots/k.jmx', conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: null : null

Comment: cause-exception     : java.lang.NullPointerException
cause-message       : null class : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBaseConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree/org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree/HTTPSampler_
line number         : 6
class[1]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter

Comment: Attach them to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to open your `/home/ksahu/MyScreenshots/k.jmx` in JMeter GUI. If it does not open - there is a problem with the code, you generated the JMX file with. In that case update your question with the code, you used to create the `k.jmx` file.

See Chapter `4. RUN A JMETER TEST THROUGH A PROGRAM (FROM JAVA CODE)` of the [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) for details.

Also there is a sample project which you can use as a reference: https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/

Comment: i have used the above code to generate the jmx file

Comment: I tried it opening by GUI mode but it throws exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the text "org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree" in the JMX generated using java to "hashTree". Open the JMX in any text editor and do the replace as mentioned. If that doesn't suffice, include the below step.

You need to set TestElement.ENABLED, TestElement.TEST_CLASS and TestElement.GUI_CLASS explicitly for each element. For example a sampler can be defined as below.

```
 HTTPSamplerProxy httpSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
        httpSampler.setDomain(DOMAIN);
        httpSampler.setPort(PORT);
        httpSampler.setPath(PATH);
        httpSampler.setMethod(METHOD);
        httpSampler.addArgument("", "${domain}");
        httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.ENABLED, true);
        httpSampler.setResponseTimeout("20000");
        httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
        httpSampler .setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
```